# Android : Chess question click a button to determine piece and then a 2nd button to determine move destination

Tags: android, button, click, onclick

I am having a rough day finding the right search syntax:)

I am building out a chess game for Android as part of an assignment.

I am suppose to use buttons.

I have board drawn and can select one button (i.e. the piece I want to move).

I can click on a piece(button) and have a toast output telling me about the current position.

My question is how do I have that first onClick wait for input for my second onClick which will be the the button/position where I want to move the piece to?

The buttons should not be pressed at the same time.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question really boils down to 'How do i track the game state'.  This is usually done using Finite State Machines.  Think of a state as a point in time for a user.  For instance, when the game is first started, you might have a board with pieces and nothing selected.  This could be state 1.

```
1
```

Now think of the transitions the user can make out of that state.  A transition can be approximated to a user interaction.  Maybe state 1 only has one transition, the player selects a piece.

```
1 -> (Player selects a piece)
```

That leads us to the second state, pieces selected.

```
1 --> (Player selects a piece) --> 2
```

Now there might be 2 transitions from state 2.  The first would be the user deselects the piece (simplifying).  The second would be the user picks a valid move (lets ignore invalid for argument).

```
1 --> (Player selects a piece) --> 2 --> (player de-selects piece)
                                     \-> (Player selects valid move)
```

Now, think about where the first transition takes you.  If there was no move, we're back at square 1, or state 1 in the diagram :)  If the piece did get moved, we probably go into a state where we are animating the move preventing input before we transition back to state 1.

```
1 --> (Player selects a piece) --> 2 --> (player de-selects piece) --> 1
                                     \-> (Player selects valid move)  --> 3 [animate] -->1
```

Once you've thought through these transitions, you can implement this state mechanism in a number of ways.  The most quick and dirty would probably be an Enum of the states with mechanism to set and get the current state in you main game class.  Then, in methods like your onClick method, when a click comes in, you check to see what state you are in before you resolve the click.  In our example, clicking on a piece in state 1 would select it, but in state 2 that same click would attempt to move a piece to that square.  The user's actions have different meaning depending on the state of the game.